# Vuex - data from different modules are returned in random order when using then()

Tags: asynchronous, promise, vue.js, store, vuex

In one of my vuex modules I'm loading data 3 times step by step with 3 different API requests using `then()`:

```
 actions: {
    loadRoamingHistory: function loadRoamingHistory(context, roamingFilter): Promise<Array<RoamingHistoryEvent>> {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {

        store.dispatch('network/loadNetworks').then(() => { 
          store.dispatch('country/loadCountries').then(() => {

            providerApi.loadRoamingHistory(roamingFilter).then(data => { 

                // read already loaded networks and countries from store
                let networks = context.rootState.network.networks;
                let countries = context.rootState.country.countries;

                // .. some data processing using informations from 
                // networks and countries request, that are not allways available at this point..

                console.log('data processing');

                commitSetRoamingHistoryEvents(context, data.roamingHistoryEvent);
                resolve();

            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
          });
        });
      });
    }  
  }
```

I also added console.log() commands to the network and country vuex setters in order to see what is executed first:

```
  mutations: {
    setNetworks: function setNetworks(state: NetworkState, networks: Array<Network>) {
      console.log('networks loaded');
      state.networks = networks;
    },
```

I would expect the 3 requests to be executed one by one, but the log messages shows that sometimes it is executed in different order, for example log messages goes like this:

> ```
> networks loaded
> countries loaded
> networks loaded
> data processing
> countries loaded
> ```

Notice that `data processing` should be last log, otherwise I cannot process the data correctly. Why it is executed in random order and what could be done in order to fix it?

Comment: actions are asynchronous, mutations are not `store.dispatch('network/loadNetworks').then(() ...` should not be needed. Also, promises are not meant to be nested, but subsequent.

Comment: How could it be changed to subsequent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, I need to correct myself, dispatch is an action, it is asynchronous, so you're correct to use promises with them. (I'm used to mapping actions, so I don't see them much)

anyway, the point of promises was to alleviate the "callback hell". so if your structure is nested like this:

- action

  - action

    - action

      - action

you're defeating the point of using a promise in the first place.

Instead the point is to chain them in a readable fashion like so

- action
- action
- action
- action

```js
actions: {
  loadRoamingHistory: function loadRoamingHistory(context, roamingFilter): Promise<Array<RoamingHistoryEvent>> {
    return store.dispatch('network/loadNetworks')
      .then(() => {
        return store.dispatch('country/loadCountries')
      })
      .then(() => {
        return providerApi.loadRoamingHistory(roamingFilter)
      })
      .then(data => { 
        // read already loaded networks and countries from store
        let networks = context.rootState.network.networks;
        let countries = context.rootState.country.countries;

        // .. some data processing using informations from 
        // networks and countries request, that are not allways available at this point..

        console.log('data processing');

        return commitSetRoamingHistoryEvents(context, data.roamingHistoryEvent);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }  
}
```

note that...
- the initial promise is not defined. Because the dispatch is asynchronous, it already creates a promise, we just add additional calls to it.
- when returning a promise inside a promise, the next `then()` will handle it, whether it is withing this function or outside of it
- your catch at the end will log an error anywhere along the chain of promises

Comment: Thx, it fixed the problem.